# Alternative for jq in debian wheezy to parse json in bash

Tags: debian, shell, software-rec, json

In Ubuntu you can simply install [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq):

```
apt-get install jq
```

But, on Debian it is not in the repository.

Is there an alternative command-line to parse a JSON string on the console?

maybe you can achieve this with python like (fantasycode):

```
cat test.json | python 'parse_json(stdin)'
```

Comment: `jq` [is available in debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=jq&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). You can get it in Debian stable via backports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One CLI json parser is [jshon](https://github.com/keenerd/jshon). Here is a simple example:

```
$ jshon -e foo -u <<< '{ "foo":"bar" }' 
bar
```

The `-e` options extract values from the json and the `-u` decodes the final string.

Answer (score 6):

jq is in Wheezy backports, and slated for Jessie

For backports on Wheezy, add the following to /etc/apt/sources.list (or a file to sources.d/???.list)

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

Then:

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install jq
```

Another alternative:

```
python -m json.tool file.json
```

Answer (score 2):

also take a look at [`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) unix utility - I developed `jtc` aiming to simply achieving JSON queries drastically:

- it's objectively faster
- easier to attain a solution (in most of the cases) - though it's subjective, until you try
- the base concept is easy to understand
- typically, `jtc` idiomatic solutions would be input data omissions resistant and invariant to input data outer structure (as long walking JSON elements retain the same relationship)

Answer (score 1):

[jp](https://github.com/jmespath/jp) is one JSON parsing CLI alternative to jq based on the Python library [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) (a pretty solid tool to depend on, it's notably the [default JSON parsing library for the AWS cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)).

While the library in question seems to be [available on Debian](https://packages.debian.org/fr/sid/python-jmespath), the jp CLI interface however doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx)

It's plain JavaScript cli JSON manipulating tool (alternative to jq) with standalone binary.

```
program | fx 'input => input.filter(x => ...).map(x => {a: a.x})'
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a cli tool called `jello` that works similarly to `jq` but allows you to use pure python code in your filters without all of the JSON loading boilerplate. Also allows you to use dot notation instead of dict bracket notation if you choose.

```
$ ip -j addr show | jello -lr '\
ips = []
for interface in _:
  for addr in interface.addr_info:
    ips.append(addr.get("local"))
ips'

127.0.0.1
::1
192.168.1.228
2600:1700:bab0:d40::49
2600:1700:bab0:d40:368d:e89e:d304:e083
fe80::9273:6fce:6df6:8f56
```

https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jello

Answer (score 0):

As my search for something like this ended me up here twice now.

A working python solution that also supports filtering like:

```
cat test.json | jq -r .myfield
```

would be:

```
cat test.json | python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.dumps(json.loads("".join([l for l in sys.stdin]))["myfield"]))'
```

Answer (score -1):

I also ended up here looking for a json command line parser which name I didn't remember :)

Turns out noone mentioned what I was looking for, so let me tell you about [jid](https://github.com/simeji/jid) - the

> json incremental digger

Comment: Please add an example how to install and how to use it. And no need for the first sentence, delete it